# XML declare padding or margin in one line for all sides

Tags: android, css, xml

I wish there was a way to specify the padding or margin of all four sides in a single line in `xml` like we do in `css`.
For example in css: `padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px;`

Do we have something like this?

Comment: Is there a problem doing that in 3 or 4 lines ?

Comment: @Umair Yes absolutely it is a problem. The most powerful warrior is time. Isn't it a problem if I have to write 4 lines instead of just one single line?

Comment: No, there isn't.  And really, if you think that amount of time matters you really don't know what you're doing.  The time you spend typing is less than 10% of the time you spend working on a project.  In fact 10% is extremely generous.  Of all the things you can optimize, that's the worst one to put effort into.

Comment: @Maseed well if you know how to use android studio you don't need to write every single line :).

Comment: Totally agreed with @GabeSechan. Even if you believe writing 4 lines will waste your time. then don't write it simple go to design screen and enter the attribute values in properties. Android studio will write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Android O DP1 introduces directional XML attributes for padding and layout_margin. Note that they take precedence over edge-specific values.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:textSize="14sp"
```

> android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/spacing_medium"
>               android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/spacing_large"

```
        />
```